# How do I make a list of all possible replaced items in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

My input is an arbitrary list, such as

```
["a","b","c"]
```

and another list element, say `"z"`. I want the output to look like:

```
[["z","b","c"],["a","z","c"],["a","b","z"]]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
replace :: [a] -> a -> [[a]]
replace []     _special = []
replace (x:xs) special  = (special:xs) : map (x:) (replace xs special)
```

Test:

```
> replace ["a","b","c"] "z"
[["z","b","c"],["a","z","c"],["a","b","z"]]
```

Explanation:

We want to produce all the lists in which exactly one element is replaced by the `special` one.

If the list is empty, there's no way to insert `special`, so we return no options.

If the list is instead `x:xs`, one option is to replace `x` and obtain `special:xs`. The other options can be computed by recursively taking any way to insert `special` in the tail `xs`, and finally prepend `x` in front of each of these.

Comment: Why inefficient? In any case, list cells before the replaced element must be copied, and after the element the tails can be shared with the input list, and the solution does just that.

Comment: @dfeuer It looks O(n^2), which is asymptotically optimal. Am I neglecting something? Any more effcient approach?

Comment: If you map `null` over the result list, it will take O(n^2) to calculate. You can make it more incremental than that; the simplest way, using base 4.7.0.2 or later, is to zip `inits` with `tails`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no efficient way to do this with lists; the best you can do, asymptotically, is

```
replace x xs = zipWith f (inits xs) (dropLast $ tails xs)
  where
    f front (_ : rear) = front ++ x : rear

dropLast [] = []
dropLast [_] = []
dropLast (x:xs) = x : dropLast xs
```

Note: this is only reasonably efficient with base 4.7.0.2 or later (GHC 7.8.4 or later).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32402969/1477667 demonstrates a cleaner way, using `tail` instead of `dropLast`.

The tricky part here is hidden in `inits`, which in recent versions goes to great lengths to be both reasonably efficient and lazy.

If you really want to make this operation fast, you have to give up on lists and use some other representation.

```
import Data.Sequence

replace :: a -> Seq a -> Seq (Seq a)
replace x xs = mapWithIndex f xs
  where
    f i _ = update i x xs
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a homework problem so this answer may not help you, but I like to solve these kinds of problems using `inits` and `tails` from the `Data.List`.

Have a look at how `inits` and `tail .tails` works:

```
as = inits [1..3]        = [ [],    [1], [1,2], [1,2,3] ]
bs = tail (tails [1..3]) = [ [2,3], [3], [] ]
cs = [1..3]              = [ 1,     2,     3]
```

Many of these kinds of problems are functions of the 3-way zip of these lists. For instance, a solution to this problem is:

```
[ a ++ "z" ++ b | (a,b) <- zip as bs ]
```

Or, if you need to add 1 to each element:

```
[ a ++ [c+1] ++ b | (a,b,c) <- zip3 as bs cs ]
```

Or remove each element:

```
[ a ++ b | (a,b) <- zip as bs ]
```

Note that even though `as` is one longer than `bs` the zip will iterate over the correct number of elements.